# Alternate 302 Redirect. Application deployed in websphere (WAS v5.1).

Tags: java, networking, websphere

Can you help me with this please.

I got a problem with my **Java Application**. In live environment, For every First or alternate request to my application is **redirecting** to another page. After refreshing the link for couple of times its working fine until we leave it idle for some time.

Its really very annoying, I don't know what causing this thing.

I did a trace with this website and found **302 redirect**. http://www.wheregoes.com

[image]

**Details:--**

Java 1.4, WebSphere Application server v5

My network admin is not available. So what can i (java developer) do to fix this. I can give you any details if you need.

Comment: It implies in your wheregoes output that it redirects to an http error 500 page. Is that correct? If so there should be some kind of error in your logs.

Comment: Also, do you know if it is your web server or application server that does the redirect?

Comment: yes it redirects to Error500.html page. I checked in WAS logs and found nothing about redirects.

Comment: I tried accessing application with internal IP address and it is working fine without any redirect. So WebspeheAppServer is not doing this redirect.